# How to parse xml in Python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup, elementtree

For this [following xml](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/13), how do I fetch the xml and then parse it to get out the value for `<age>`?

```
<boardgames>
  <boardgame objectid="13">
  <yearpublished>1995</yearpublished>
  <minplayers>3</minplayers>
  <maxplayers>4</maxplayers>
  <playingtime>90</playingtime>
  <age>10</age>
  <name sortindex="1">Catan</name>
  ...
```

I'm currently trying:

```
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=game_url)
xml = ElementTree.fromstring(result.content)
```

But I'm not sure I'm on the right path.  When I try to parse I get errors (I think because the xml is not valid xml).

Comment: Works fine when I grab the page with `urllib2`: `xml = ElementTree.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgam
e/13').read())`

Comment: I'm getting the xml, but I don't know how to use ElementTree to grab the values of individual elements.  So how do I grab the value for <age>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
import urllib2
from xml.etree import ElementTree

result = urllib2.urlopen('http://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/13').read()
xml = ElementTree.fromstring(result)
print xml.findtext(".//age")
```

Answer (score 7):

`xml.findtext('age')` or `xml.findtext('boardgames/age')` would normally get you the 10 inside `<age>10</age>`, but the parsing appears to fail due to invalid xml. `ElementTree` does a rather poor job of parsing invalid xml in my experience.

Instead use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which handles invalid xml well.

```
content = urllib2.urlopen('http://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/13').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print soup.find('age').string
```