# Consuming XML string with Python

Tags: python, xml, soap

I need help to consume a XML string from a SOAP server and it's working with the data in first row (or parent nodes) but when I try to get data inside (child nodes) with two or more data, just get one. Maybe a loop will help me, but I can't figure it out how to do it. Here is a example of the response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <PedidosDisponiveisResponse xmlns="http:...">
            <PedidosDisponiveisResult>
                <ResultadoOperacao>
                    <Codigo>200001</Codigo>
                    <Descricao>Operação "Selecionar os pedidos disponiveis na integração" efetuada com sucesso. - I35249DCD</Descricao>
                    <Tipo>tdreSucesso</Tipo>
                </ResultadoOperacao>
                <VersaoWebService>50.106.92.0</VersaoWebService>
                <Rows>
                    <DadosPedidosDisponiveisWeb>
                        <CodigoPedidoAbacos>4967302</CodigoPedidoAbacos>
                        <NumeroDoPedido>2000007159352944</NumeroDoPedido>
                        <SequencialNumeroPedido>0</SequencialNumeroPedido>
                        <ProtocoloPedido>sdf-sdf</ProtocoloPedido>
                        <Comercializacao>MATRIZ - VENDA DE PRODUTOS OMNI                   </Comercializacao>
                        <GrupoComercializacao>VENDA                                             </GrupoComercializacao>
                        <StatusPedido>DESPACHADO                                        </StatusPedido>
                        <Acao>aieManutencao</Acao>
                        <PedidoWeb>
                            <ResultadoOperacao>
                                <Codigo>200001</Codigo>
                                <Descricao>Operação "Selecionar os dados do pedido que está disponivel na integração" efetuada com sucesso.</Descricao>
                                <Tipo>tdreSucesso</Tipo>
                            </ResultadoOperacao>
                            <Rows>
                                <DadosPedidoWeb>
                                    <CodigoPedido>4902</CodigoPedido>
                                    <NumeroPedido>20059352944</NumeroPedido>
                                    <CodigoUnidadeNegocio>5</CodigoUnidadeNegocio>
                                    <EMail>asd@asd.com</EMail>
                                    <CodigoCliente>1082</CodigoCliente>
                                    <ClienteCPFouCNPJ>99999999999</ClienteCPFouCNPJ>
                                    <RepresentanteVendas>1</RepresentanteVendas>
                                    <CodigoRepresentanteExterno>1</CodigoRepresentanteExterno>
                                    <ValorPedido>99.8</ValorPedido>
                                    <ValorFrete>71.07</ValorFrete>
                                    <ValorEncargos>0</ValorEncargos>
                                    <ValorDesconto>19900.2</ValorDesconto>
                                    <DataVenda>654987 00:00:00.000</DataVenda>
                                    <CodigoTransportadora>3</CodigoTransportadora>
                                    <Transportadora>sdf</Transportadora>
                                    <ServicoEntrega>sdf</ServicoEntrega>
                                    <CodigoAdministrativoServicoEntrega>1510</CodigoAdministrativoServicoEntrega>
                                    <TransportadoraCNPJ>987654321</TransportadoraCNPJ>
                                    <Canal>OmniOne                                           </Canal>
                                    <SubCanal>Formigão                                          </SubCanal>
                                    <EmitirNotaSimbolica>N</EmitirNotaSimbolica>
                                    <DataPrazoEntregaFinal />
                                    <OptouNFPaulista>S</OptouNFPaulista>
                                    <MensagemCorpoNota />
                                    <DiasEntregaPosPagamento />
                                    <DataPrazoEntrega>19012024 00:00:00.000</DataPrazoEntrega>
                                    <DestNome>nononononononno</DestNome>
                                    <DestEndereco>nononon</DestEndereco>
                                    <DestEnderecoLogradouro>nononn</DestEnderecoLogradouro>
                                    <DestEnderecoNumero>12654    </DestEnderecoNumero>
                                    <DestEnderecoComplemento>Referencia:nonononono</DestEnderecoComplemento>
                                    <DestBairro>sdfsdf</DestBairro>
                                    <DestCep>987654</DestCep>
                                    <DestMunicipio>sdf</DestMunicipio>
                                    <DestEstado>sdf</DestEstado>
                                    <DestPais>BRASIL                                            </DestPais>
                                    <DestSexo>E</DestSexo>
                                    <DestEmail>sdf</DestEmail>
                                    <DestTelefone>654</DestTelefone>
                                    <DestTipoPessoa>F</DestTipoPessoa>
                                    <DestCPFouCNPJ654987</DestCPFouCNPJ>
                                    <DestInscricaoEstadual>sdf</DestInscricaoEstadual>
                                    <DestInscricaoMunicipal />
                                    <DestCodigoIBGE>54</DestCodigoIBGE>
                                    <Anotacoes>
                                        <ResultadoOperacao>
                                            <Codigo>200001</Codigo>
                                            <Descricao>Operação "Selecionar as anotações do pedido" efetuada com sucesso.</Descricao>
                                            <Tipo>tdreSucesso</Tipo>
                                        </ResultadoOperacao>
                                        <Rows>
                                            <DadosPedidoAnotacaoWeb>
                                                <CodigoPedido>897</CodigoPedido>
                                                <Anotacao>Frete: 0 Obs: collectorcollector paid,not_delivered,Dest: Felipe Demosthenes</Anotacao>
                                                <DataAnotacao>654</DataAnotacao>
                                                <ClassificacaoAnotacao>COMERCIAL                                         </ClassificacaoAnotacao>
                                            </DadosPedidoAnotacaoWeb>
                                            <DadosPedidoAnotacaoWeb>
                                                <CodigoPedido>8</CodigoPedido>
                                                <Anotacao>sdf</Anotacao>
                                                <DataAnotacao>15122023 12:20:25.507</DataAnotacao>
                                                <ClassificacaoAnotacao>CRÉDITO                                           </ClassificacaoAnotacao>
                                            </DadosPedidoAnotacaoWeb>
                                        </Rows>
                                    </Anotacoes>
                                    <EstoqueReservado>S</EstoqueReservado>
                                    <PreVenda>Não</PreVenda>
                                    <TipoFrete />
                                </DadosPedidoWeb>
                            </Rows>
                        </PedidoWeb>
                        <PedidoItens>
                            <ResultadoOperacao>
                                <Codigo>200001</Codigo>
                                <Descricao>Operação "Selecionar os dados dos itens do pedido que está disponivel na integração e com estoque reservado" efetuada com sucesso.</Descricao>
                                <Tipo>tdreSucesso</Tipo>
                            </ResultadoOperacao>
                            <Rows>
***# **                                <DadosPedidoItensWeb>
#                                     <CodigoItem>7</CodigoItem>
#                                     <CodigoProdutoAbacos>1</CodigoProdutoAbacos>
#                                     <CodigoProduto>1</CodigoProduto>
#                                     <Quantidade>1</Quantidade>
#                                     <PrecoUnitarioLiquido>49.9</PrecoUnitarioLiquido>
#                                     <PrecoUnitarioBruto>10000</PrecoUnitarioBruto>
#                                     <QuantidadeReservada>0</QuantidadeReservada>
#                                     <PersonalizacaoNome />
#                                     <PersonalizacaoTexto />
#                                     <NomeProduto>Lente Farol Fiesta 03/07 Ld</NomeProduto>
#                                     <NomeComposto>Lente Farol Fiesta 03/07 Ld * Direito Passageiro * GRUPO * CAMBUCI</NomeComposto>
#                                     <CodigoBarras>654</CodigoBarras>
#                                     <Classe>ACABADO                                           </Classe>
#                                     <TipoItem>NORMAL</TipoItem>
#                                     <CodigoRastreabilidade />
#                                     <DataValidade />
#                                     <DataVencimentoGarantia />
#                                     <PreVenda>Não</PreVenda>
#                                     <Rastreabilidade>
#                                         <ResultadoOperacao>
#                                             <Codigo>200003</Codigo>
#                                             <Descricao>OK, porém não há dados.</Descricao>
#                                             <Tipo>tdreSucessoSemDados</Tipo>
#                                         </ResultadoOperacao>
#                                     </Rastreabilidade>
#                                 </DadosPedidoItensWeb>
#                                 <DadosPedidoItensWeb>
#                                     <CodigoItem>5</CodigoItem>
#                                     <CodigoProdutoAbacos>1</CodigoProdutoAbacos>
#                                     <CodigoProduto>5</CodigoProduto>
#                                     <Quantidade>1</Quantidade>
#                                     <PrecoUnitarioLiquido>49.9</PrecoUnitarioLiquido>
#                                     <PrecoUnitarioBruto>10000</PrecoUnitarioBruto>
#                                     <QuantidadeReservada>0</QuantidadeReservada>
#                                     <PersonalizacaoNome />
#                                     <PersonalizacaoTexto />
#                                     <NomeProduto>Lente Farol Fiesta 03/07 Le</NomeProduto>
#                                     <NomeComposto>Lente Farol Fiesta 03/07 Le * Esquerdo Motorista * GRUPO * CAMBUCI</NomeComposto>
#                                     <CodigoBarras>2</CodigoBarras>
#                                     <Classe>ACABADO                                           </Classe>
#                                     <TipoItem>NORMAL</TipoItem>
#                                     <CodigoRastreabilidade />
#                                     <DataValidade />
#                                     <DataVencimentoGarantia />
#                                     <PreVenda>Não</PreVenda>
#                                     <Rastreabilidade>
#                                         <ResultadoOperacao>
#                                             <Codigo>200003</Codigo>
#                                             <Descricao>OK, porém não há dados.</Descricao>
#                                             <Tipo>tdreSucessoSemDados</Tipo>
#                                         </ResultadoOperacao>
#                                     </Rastreabilidade>
#                                 </DadosPedidoItensWeb>*****
                            </Rows>
                        </PedidoItens>
                        <PedidoPagamento>
                            <ResultadoOperacao>
                                <Codigo>200001</Codigo>
                                <Descricao>Operação "Selecionar os dados dos pagamentos do pedido que está disponivel na integração" efetuada com sucesso.</Descricao>
                                <Tipo>tdreSucesso</Tipo>
                            </ResultadoOperacao>
                            <Rows>
                                <DadosPedidoPagamentoWeb>
                                    <CodigoPagamentoAbacos>1</CodigoPagamentoAbacos>
                                    <FormaPagamentoCodigo>14</FormaPagamentoCodigo>
                                    <FormaPagamento>sdf                                     </FormaPagamento>
                                    <TipoFormaPagamentoSigla>CA</TipoFormaPagamentoSigla>
                                    <Valor>170.87</Valor>
                                    <ValorPago>170.87</ValorPago>
                                    <TIDGateway />
                                    <Autorizacao />
                                    <NSU />
                                    <DataPagamento>15122023 00:00:00.000</DataPagamento>
                                    <DataVencimentoBoleto>15122023 12:20:25.290</DataVencimentoBoleto>
                                    <CondicaoPagamento />
                                    <QuantidadeParcelasCartao>1</QuantidadeParcelasCartao>
                                    <CMC7 />
                                    <Parcelas>
                                        <ResultadoOperacao>
                                            <Codigo>200001</Codigo>
                                            <Descricao>Operação "Parcelas dos pagamento com cartão" efetuada com sucesso.</Descricao>
                                            <Tipo>tdreSucesso</Tipo>
                                        </ResultadoOperacao>
                                        <Rows>
                                            <DadosPedidoPagamentoParcelasWeb>
                                                <DataAprovacao>15122023</DataAprovacao>
                                                <DataProvisaoPagamento>15122023</DataProvisaoPagamento>
                                                <ValorBruto>170.87</ValorBruto>
                                                <NumeroParcela>1</NumeroParcela>
                                                <QuantidadeParcelas>1</QuantidadeParcelas>
                                                <CodigoNSU />
                                                <CodigoAutorizacao />
                                            </DadosPedidoPagamentoParcelasWeb>
                                        </Rows>
                                    </Parcelas>
                                    <PagamentoBoleto>
                                        <ResultadoOperacao>
                                            <Codigo>200003</Codigo>
                                            <Descricao>OK, porém não há dados.</Descricao>
                                            <Tipo>tdreSucessoSemDados</Tipo>
                                        </ResultadoOperacao>
                                        <Rows />
                                    </PagamentoBoleto>
                                    <CNPJCredenciadora>54</CNPJCredenciadora>
                                    <Bandeira>99</Bandeira>
                                    <ValorDescontoFinanceiro>0</ValorDescontoFinanceiro>
                                </DadosPedidoPagamentoWeb>
                            </Rows>
                        </PedidoPagamento>
                        <ProcessoTroca>
                            <ResultadoOperacao>
                                <Codigo>200003</Codigo>
                                <Descricao>OK, porém não há dados.</Descricao>
                                <Tipo>tdreSucessoSemDados</Tipo>
                            </ResultadoOperacao>
                            <Rows>
                                <DadosProcessoTrocaWeb>
                                    <CodigoInternoNotaOrigem>0</CodigoInternoNotaOrigem>
                                    <CodigoInternoPedidoOrigem>0</CodigoInternoPedidoOrigem>
                                    <CodigoExternoPedidoOrigem />
                                </DadosProcessoTrocaWeb>
                            </Rows>
                        </ProcessoTroca>
                    </DadosPedidosDisponiveisWeb>
```

I need to get all two or more data inside `DadosPedidoItensWeb`.

Could anyone help me? I'm developing in Python with SQL Server.

Here is the my code:

```
import logging
import pyodbc
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO
import datetime



def handle_soap_request(url: str, headers: dict, body: str, db_connection_string: str) -> None:
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
        response_content = response.content.decode("utf-8")
        response_content = response_content.replace('&#x0;', '')


        

        xml_io = StringIO(response_content)
        
        
        

        for event, element in ET.iterparse(xml_io, events=("start", "end")):
            if event == "start" and element.tag == '{http://www.kplsolucoes.com.br/ABACOSWebService}DadosPedidosDisponiveisWeb':
                try:
                    codigoPedidoAbacos, numeroDoPedido, protocoloPedido, comercializacao, grupoComercializacao, codigoUnidadeNegocio, codigoCliente, valorPedido, valorFrete, valorEncargos, valorDesconto, dataVenda, codigoTransportadora, transportadora, servicoEntrega, transportadoraCNPJ, canal, subCanal, destCep, destMunicipio, destEstado, codigoProdutoAbacos, codigoProduto, precoUnitarioLiquido, precoUnitarioBruto, quantidadeReservada, nomeProduto, nomeComposto, codigoBarras, classe, codigoItem = (
                        element.findtext(f".//{{http://www.kplsolucoes.com.br/ABACOSWebService}}{tag}")
                        for tag in [
                            "CodigoPedidoAbacos",
                            "NumeroDoPedido",
                            "ProtocoloPedido",
                            "Comercializacao",
                            "GrupoComercializacao",
                            "CodigoUnidadeNegocio",
                            "CodigoCliente",
                            "ValorPedido",
                            "ValorFrete",
                            "ValorEncargos",
                            "ValorDesconto",
                            "DataVenda",
                            "CodigoTransportadora",
                            "Transportadora",
                            "ServicoEntrega",
                            "TransportadoraCNPJ",
                            "Canal",
                            "SubCanal",
                            "DestCep",
                            "DestMunicipio",
                            "DestEstado",
                            "CodigoProdutoAbacos",
                            "CodigoProduto",
                            "PrecoUnitarioLiquido",
                            "PrecoUnitarioBruto",
                            "QuantidadeReservada",
                            "NomeProduto",
                            "NomeComposto",
                            "CodigoBarras",
                            "Classe",
                            "CodigoItem"
                            
                            
                            
                        ]
                    )
                except ET.ParseError as e:
                    logging.warning("Error processing row: %s", e)
                    continue
                

                if dataVenda:
                    try:
                        dataVenda = datetime.datetime.strptime(dataVenda, '%d%m%Y %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
                    except ValueError as e:
                        logging.warning("Error processing date: %s", e)
                
                    
                    
                    
                             
               
                    
                
                    
                    
                

                
                        # Primary key value does not exist, insert a new row
                    insert_new_row(cursor, codigoPedidoAbacos, numeroDoPedido, protocoloPedido, comercializacao, grupoComercializacao, codigoUnidadeNegocio, codigoCliente, valorPedido, valorFrete, valorEncargos, valorDesconto, dataVenda, codigoTransportadora, transportadora, servicoEntrega, transportadoraCNPJ, canal, subCanal, destCep, destMunicipio, destEstado, codigoProdutoAbacos, codigoProduto, precoUnitarioLiquido, precoUnitarioBruto, quantidadeReservada, nomeProduto, nomeComposto, codigoBarras, classe, codigoItem)
                    logging.info('New row ITEM inserted for CodigoItem: %s', codigoItem)
                    logging.info("Time: " + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))
                    
                    



                connection.commit()
                element.clear()

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('An error with occurred: %s', e)
        pass

        
        

        
        
        


def insert_new_row(cursor, codigoPedidoAbacos, numeroDoPedido, protocoloPedido, comercializacao, grupoComercializacao, codigoUnidadeNegocio, codigoCliente, valorPedido, valorFrete, valorEncargos, valorDesconto, dataVenda, codigoTransportadora, transportadora, servicoEntrega, transportadoraCNPJ, canal, subCanal, destCep, destMunicipio, destEstado, codigoProdutoAbacos, codigoProduto, precoUnitarioLiquido, precoUnitarioBruto, quantidadeReservada, nomeProduto, nomeComposto, codigoBarras, classe, codigoItem):
    
    if codigoItem is not None:
       cursor.execute('INSERT INTO pedidosTeste ([CodigoPedidoAbacos], [NumeroDoPedido], [ProtocoloPedido], [Comercializacao], [GrupoComercializacao], [CodigoUnidadeNegocio], [CodigoCliente], [ValorPedido], [ValorFrete], [ValorEncargos], [ValorDesconto], [DataVenda], [CodigoTransportadora], [Transportadora], [ServicoEntrega], [TransportadoraCNPJ], [Canal], [SubCanal], [DestCep], [DestMunicipio], [DestEstado], [CodigoProdutoAbacos], [CodigoProduto], [PrecoUnitarioLiquido], [PrecoUnitarioBruto], [QuantidadeReservada], [NomeProduto], [NomeComposto], [CodigoBarras], [Classe], [CodigoItem]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', 
        (codigoPedidoAbacos, numeroDoPedido, protocoloPedido, comercializacao, grupoComercializacao, codigoUnidadeNegocio, codigoCliente, valorPedido, valorFrete, valorEncargos, valorDesconto, dataVenda, codigoTransportadora, transportadora, servicoEntrega, transportadoraCNPJ, canal, subCanal, destCep, destMunicipio, destEstado, codigoProdutoAbacos, codigoProduto, precoUnitarioLiquido, precoUnitarioBruto, quantidadeReservada, nomeProduto, nomeComposto, codigoBarras, classe, codigoItem))
    else:
        logging.warning("CodigoItem is None. Skipping row insertion.")
```

I have tried this way, but still getting one Item:

def handle_soap_request(url: str, headers: dict, body: str, db_connection_string: str) -> None:
try:
response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
response_content = response.content.decode("utf-8")
response_content = response_content.replace('�', '')

```
    xml_io = StringIO(response_content)
    
    
    

    for event, element in ET.iterparse(xml_io, events=("start", "end")):
        if event == "start" and element.tag.endswith("DadosPedidosDisponiveisWeb"):
            try:
                namespace = "{http://www.kplsolucoes.com.br/ABACOSWebService}"
                codigoPedidoAbacos = element.findtext(f".//{namespace}CodigoPedidoAbacos")
                numeroDoPedido = element.findtext(f".//{namespace}NumeroDoPedido")
                codigoItem = element.findtext(f".//{namespace}CodigoItem")
                protocoloPedido = element.findtext(f".//{namespace}ProtocoloPedido")
                # Continue processing the data...
            except ET.ParseError as e:
                logging.warning("Error processing row: %s", e)
                continue
```

Comment: "it's working with the data in first row (or parent nodes) but when I try to get data inside (child nodes) with two or more data, just get one." - please show us your code. See also [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for answer me @mzjn! Sorry, but how can i send here my code? Button Answer my Question?

Comment: @MarcosRibeiro [edit] your question and put the code there (with correct formatting)

Comment: I did it right?

Comment: Your code has a default namespace : <PedidosDisponiveisResponse xmlns="http:...">

Comment: Sorry @jdweng, but what i have to do?

Comment: Even if I have only one response, maybe a For Loop? How would be the best way? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Here is using findtext with a namespace : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122681/xml-parsing-problem-in-python-cannot-find-findtext

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I'll try it now and I give you a feedback!! Thanks!!

Comment: Please share a valid xml example. with findall(xpath, namespace) you get a list of all tags content.

Comment: Hi @Hermann12 i'll get a file here and post ok?

Comment: @MarcosRibeiro your shared  xml snippet is not valid.

Comment: Sorry @Hermann12 dumb here!! LOL What I need to do now? Can you show me the way?

Comment: Hi Guys!! I did it, just using for loop inside namespace - thanks to you all -  for codigoItem in codigoItems:
                        
                        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO pedidosTeste (CodigoPedidoAbacos, NumeroDoPedido, CodigoItem) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (codigoPedidoAbacos, numeroDoPedido, codigoItem.text))

Comment: @MarcosRibeiro, you skiped important values for namesace e.g. <PedidosDisponiveisResponse xmlns="http:...">and please remove your # *** signs. Close all tags, that the structure of the xml  is clear. You can validate your xml snippet [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)